# Can #define have multi parameters?

Tags: c

Hi  wanted to create a define that has two or even three params is this possible ??

Example

```
#define my_define(param1,param2,param3)\
if (param1) \
{/*do something */} \
if (param2) \
{/*do something */} \
if (param3) \
{/*do something */}
```

Comment: Have you tried? What problems you found?

Comment: Yes, but your macro body could use a little work if you want this to be a true general-purpose macro. Change the `if`s to `else if` and add an `else;` at the end. Or, probably better, wrap the whole thing in `do { ... } while(0)`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `#define` macro's can have more than one parameter.

Specifically, C99 specifies that a compliant implementation has to be able to deal with at least 127 parameters for a macro (it used to be 31 in C89).

Comment: and even a variable number of parameters, with `#define something(...) something_else(__VA_ARGS__)`

Comment: Annoying nitpick: C99 *is* ANSI C.  ANSI issued the original C standard in 1989; ISO adopted it with editorial changes (renumbered the sections, for example), and then ANSI adopted the 1990 ISO standard.  The standard was amended slightly in 1995.  ISO issued a new standard in 1999 and ANSI adopted it, superseding the 1990 standard, which now has no official standing.  The term "ANSI C" is very commonly used to refer to the old 1989 or 1990 version of the standard, but to avoid any ambiguity it's best to refer to the date (C89/C90, C95, C99, C201X).  (I told you it would be annoying!)

Comment: @Keith : not annoying. Calling C89/C90 "ANSI C" is just a hard habit to lose.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to determine how many arguments were passed to a function, you can use this:

```
#include <stdarg.h>

#define __VA_NARGS__(...) __VA_NARGS__N(__VA_ARGS__,64,63,62,61,60,59,58,57,56,55,54,53,52,51,50,49,48,47,46,45,44,43,42,41,40,39,38,37,36,35,34,33,32,31,30,29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21,20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0)
#define __VA_NARGS__N(_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41,_42,_43,_44,_45,_46,_47,_48,_49,_50,_51,_52,_53,_54,_55,_56,_57,_58,_59,_60,_61,_62,_63,_64,N,...) N

#define sum(...) _sum (__VA_NARGS__(__VA_ARGS__), __VA_ARGS__)
int _sum (numargs, ...) {
    int total = 0;
    va_list args;

    va_start (args, numargs);
    for (; numargs > 0; numargs--) {
        total += va_arg (args, int);
    }
    va_end (args);

    return (total);
}
```